# PreviewMouseDown occur before the SelectionChanged

Tags: wpf

I try to get selected value of ListView by checking SelectedItem in PreviewMouseDown event handler.

But, PreviewMouseDown occured before SelectedItem , so i get old selected value.

How can i get the updated selected value?

Comment: any reason you can't use MouseDown instead of PreviewMouseDown?

Comment: I need get click event in father control, so i need bubbling event. MouseDown fire events to childrens not to parent, so it does not feet ny needs.
Thank you

Comment: MouseDownEvent is also routed event, and bubble to parents, if someone handle it you can use AddHandler with last argument of true, try this please

Comment: Just remember that items can be selected with the keyboard as well.

Comment: Do you need to know about something what occurred before or after SelectedItem happens?

Comment: Just to explain, the Preview Events are usually always fired before the actual event so the selection is done in the base MouseDown, so in the previewmousedown, Mousedown wasn't yet called. And i aggree with ArsenMkrt, why not use Mousedown?

Comment: Thank to all, i does:
recipeListsControl.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Mouse_Down), true);
Now, i have ability to get MouseDown event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I does, as "ArsenMkrt" and "Wallstreet Programmer" suggests to me:

In xaml, my control:

```
 <loc:RecipeListsControl x:Name="recipeListsControl" DataContext="{Binding Path=RecipeLists}"/>
```

In code behind:

```
 recipeListsControl.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Mouse_Down), true);
 recipeListsControl.AddHandler(UIElement.KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(Key_Down), true);
```

Thanks, guys